# Having a number of elements that we want to organize in a number of sets find a general formula

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have $32$ elements that we want to organize in $8$ sets of $4$ elements each by random

**1.** In how many ways can we create de sets?

**2.** Deduce from the past headland a general formula for the number of possible distributions of $  m \times n $ objects (distinguishables) in $n $ sets (undistinguisables) of $m$ objects each

**3.** Given three elements $ A,B,C  $ in how many cases will those be in the same set?

**4.** In how many cases will $A$ and $B $ be in the same set while $C$ will be in any other set?

This is what I think:

For **1.** I think the solution is $ {32 \choose 8} \times 4$. But i think i don't get well what **2.** wants me to do, would this keep being $ {m \times n \choose n} \times m$  ?

For **3.** I think the solution is $ \frac{1}{8} \times  \frac{1}{8}  $ and for **4.** I think the solution is $ \frac{1}{8} \times  \frac{7}{8}  $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1).Imagine a linear array of 32 elements with partitions after every 8 places we have 4 sub-boxes. Arrange all object over these. Consider each box as a group. Now permutation within the groups must be removed ($8!^4$), and permutations of group must also be removed($4!$):
$$\frac{32!}{8!^44!}$$
(2).Similarly:
$$\frac{(mn)!}{m!^{n}n!}$$
(3).This is easy, just put them together in any three places of a group/sub-box and arrange rest:
$$\frac{(32-3)!3!/(8!^44!)}{32!/(8!^44!)}=\frac{29!3!}{32!}=\frac{3.2.1}{32.31.30}=\frac{1}{4960}$$ 
(4).Similiarly:
$$\frac{(32-3)!2!1!/(8!^44!)}{32!/(8!^44!)}=\frac{29!2!1!}{32!}=\frac{2.1.1}{32.31.30}=\frac{1}{14880}$$